# CPU Scheduling policy (by multi thread)

Tags: operating-system

In general Operation system reference book like Operating system concepts...

When it explain the CPU scheduling (FCFS, RR, ...),

I think that sounds like single CPU / single thread by default.

so, I wonder if that applies to single CPU / multi-thread by default.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about operating system design and not a specific programming problem. http://cs.stackexchange.com may be a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

thread is the smallest of cpu scheduling unit, so i think it's also applies to single CPU / multi-thread.

Answer (score 0):

A single CPU (or core, to be exact) can run only one thread at a time. The OS gives the impression of multitasking by constantly switching which thread is run.

If your question is about difference between single-core CPUs and multi-core CPUs, multi-core CPUs are handled in the same way as multiple single-core CPUs.